# PHP responses nothing when requesting from iOS App (Swift)

Tags: php, ios, swift, multipartform-data

I wrote a simple HTTP POST Request in my iOS App written in Swift 4.

The Swift code is as below:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/api.php")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let body = NSMutableData()

// Text parameter: Action
body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\n" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format: ("my_action" as NSString)).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

// Text parameter: Peer ID
body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"peerid\"\r\n\r\n" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format: ("123456" as NSString)).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

// Image
body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"secret_img\"; filename=\"secret.jpg\"\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(imageData!)
body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

request.httpBody = body as Data

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        return
    }

    guard let data = data else {
        return
    }

    do {
        // create json object from response Json data 
        /*if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
         print(json)
         // handle json...
        }*/

        // Debug: check the response string
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
})
task.resume()
```

The PHP responses with empty string (no error is reported). Then, I use a simple HTML form to test whether the PHP script is okay. Here is the `form.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test Upload Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_action" />
    <input type="hidden" name="peerid" value="123456" />
    <p>Image: <input type="file" name="secret_img" required /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP responses with:

```
{"status": "OK"}
```

which proves the script has no problem. The PHP script is as follow, which is dead simple:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(!isset($_FILES['secret_img'])) {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'missing image'));
    exit;
}
$file = $_FILES['secret_img'];
$upload_folder = 'upload/';
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['secret_img']['tmp_name'], $upload_folder . $_POST['peerid'] . '_' . time() . '_' . rand(1000, 999999) . '.jpg')) {
    // success
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'OK'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'unable to copy image'));
}
?>
```

I narrowed down the error to Swift code. I remove the contents in the `body` (commenting out `body.append()` lines), then the PHP responses with:

```
{"error": "missing image"}
```

which is the normal behavior.

Can you guys help me spot the problem? Thanks.

---

**UPDATE** If I add the following 2 lines before the `request.httpBody` line, the `dump()` returns `nil`. What's going on?

```
let debug = NSString(data: body as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
dump(debug)
```

the `body` variable is properly initialized and data are appended without error.

Comment: I think the last boundary in the body has extra `--` at the end, After adding image data `NSString(format: "\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary)` try this.

Comment: Just tried your code, it works on my local machine. PHP responds with `{"status":"OK"}`

Comment: @Cristik really? I still can't this right.

Comment: Well, perhaps the problem is specific to your machine, on mine I got the expected PHP response, and also checked the file and it was correctly uploaded.

Comment: I just notice that server responded with HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden). Maybe the server thinks the `httpBody` is malformed.

Comment: More likely it's an Apache configuration issue.

Comment: I finally spotted the error. It's the boundary and change line issues. Will explain in separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is subtle and not easy to spot. The cause of the problem is:

- the boundary is not set correctly
- some change lines `\r\n` are missing / duplicated

To rectify the problem, the `httpBody` has to change to the followings:

```
let body = NSMutableData()

// Text parameter: Action
body.append(NSString(format: "--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\n" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format: "my_action\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
```

In the first block, the first `\r\n` is not necessary (which caused an empty line in the `httpBody`), and (to align with the format), the first `\r\n` of the second block is moved to the tail of `my_action` string.

```
// Text parameter: Peer ID
body.append(NSString(format: "--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"peerid\"\r\n\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format: "123456\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
```

Same with the first block, the `\r\n` is re-arranged (not related to 403 Forbidden issue). Also simplified some codes.

```
// Image
body.append(NSString(format: "--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"secret_img\"; filename=\"secret.jpg\"\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
body.append(imageData!)
body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

request.httpBody = body as Data
```

The last block is problematic, causing the 403 Forbidden error. The last line missed the ending boundary symbol.

The resultant content is as follow:

```
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"
my_action

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="peerid"
123456

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="secret_img"; filename="secret.jpg"
{image data here}

--boundary--
```

Conclusion: The missing ending boundary caused 403 Forbidden (malformed HTTP body).

The fix is inspired from the `Content-Disposition` documentation at MDN: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition